# Query group by a column and return JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below:

| id | mid | handphone | coupono | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0811111111 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 08222222222 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 08222222222 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 08222222222 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 08111111111 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 08333333333 | 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 08333333333 | 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | 08444444444 | 8 | 1 |
| ----- | ----- | --------------- | -------- | ------- |

I want to query the table using `WHERE` clause on `mId` column and filtered the `couponno` or listed on `handphone` number. How to query that?

The result that I want is:

```json
{
  "08111111111": [{
    "Id": 1,
    "CouponNo": 1,
    "Status": 1
  }, {
    "Id": 5,
    "CouponNo": 5,
    "Status": 1
  }],
  "08222222222": [{
    "Id": 2,
    "CouponNo": 2,
    "Status": 1
  }, {
    "Id": 3,
    "CouponNo": 3,
    "Status": 1
  }, {
    "Id": 4,
    "CouponNo": 4,
    "Status": 1
  }]
}
```

Comment: [for json documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: It's good to see what is your current attempt and what problems do you face.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Are you sure that's the JSON format you need to use? Having data values (instead of column names) as object keys leads to pivot acrobatics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requiring `Handphone` to be object keys in your JSON makes it difficult to produce from SQL and probably won't scale well on the receiving side either as you add more data over time.

Here is some pivot-based SQL that will produce your desired JSON...

```sql
create table dbo.PivotJsonStuff (
  Id int,
  [Mid] int,
  Handphone varchar(11),
  CouponNo int,
  Status int
);

insert dbo.PivotJsonStuff (Id, [Mid], Handphone, CouponNo, Status)
values
  (1, 1, '08111111111', 1, 1),
  (2, 1, '08222222222', 2, 1),
  (3, 1, '08222222222', 3, 1),
  (4, 1, '08222222222', 4, 1),
  (5, 1, '08111111111', 5, 1),
  (6, 2, '08333333333', 6, 1),
  (7, 2, '08333333333', 7, 1),
  (8, 2, '08444444444', 8, 1);

select
  [08111111111] = json_query([08111111111]),
  [08222222222] = json_query([08222222222])
from (
  select Handphone,
    [JSON] = (
      select PJS2.Id, PJS2.CouponNo, PJS2.Status
      from dbo.PivotJsonStuff PJS2
      where PJS2.Handphone = PJS1.Handphone
      for json path
    )
  from dbo.PivotJsonStuff PJS1
  group by Handphone
) src
pivot (max([JSON]) for Handphone in ([08111111111], [08222222222])) pvt
for json path, without_array_wrapper;
```

```json
{
    "08111111111": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "CouponNo": 1,
            "Status": 1
        },
        {
            "Id": 5,
            "CouponNo": 5,
            "Status": 1
        }
    ],
    "08222222222": [
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "CouponNo": 2,
            "Status": 1
        },
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "CouponNo": 3,
            "Status": 1
        },
        {
            "Id": 4,
            "CouponNo": 4,
            "Status": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: yes, thank you. I'll try your solution to make function in store procedure.. but for now I used linq for ToLookUp like 
```c#
            Lookup<string, string> lookup = (Lookup<string, string>)_ctx.Coupon.ToLookup(c 
 => c.Handphone, c => c.CouponNo);

```